# Custom objective function in PuLP

Tags: python, optimization

I have defined an objective function called "optimizer()"

```
def optimizer(stocks,allocations):
    #stocks = list of tickers, allocations = list of allocations
...
...
    return sharpes['sharpe']
```

I pre-define the stocks, so those won't change, but I want to find the optimal allocation that maximizes sharpe with constraint that the sum of allocations == 1. X and Y are the percentages of stocks in a portfolio.

```
sharpes = LpProblem("Sharpe_Problem", LpMaximize)
x = LpVariable('x', lowBound = 0,upBound = 1,cat="Continuous")
y = LpVariable('y', lowBound = 0,upBound = 1,cat="Continuous")
sharpes += x + y == 1
sharpes += optimizer(stocks,[x,y])
```

However, when I try to run this, I am getting:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py in __truediv__(self, other)
    994         if isinstance(other, LpAffineExpression) or isinstance(other, LpVariable):
    995             if len(other):
--> 996                 raise TypeError(
    997                     "Expressions cannot be divided by a non-constant expression"
    998                 )

TypeError: Expressions cannot be divided by a non-constant expression
```

I believe that there is something wrong with the way that x and y are being passed into the optimizer function. If I run optimizer() by itself and give it an array of x,y values, it works fine. Perhaps because the optimizer function is non-linear?

Comment: the function is empty, so are you asking about the block of code in the middle of the question ?

Comment: i excluded the details of the function for simplicity

Comment: I don't think you have a good understanding of LP frameworks like `pulp`.  You *cannot* just add in arbitrary functions for it to optimize.  You must provide expressions in terms of the variables for it to construct a model.  Arbitrary functions are not supported.  You might look at a different framework such as `scipy.minimize` that I believe works with arbitrary functions.